# What kind of clause is "reading about the places I am going to visit on the Internet and in books" in this sentence?

Tags: clauses

"My first piece of advice is to work hard on your research before you go if you want to make your trip enjoyable and rewarding. I plan my trips very carefully for at least three months before I leave, **reading about the places I am going to visit on the Internet and in books."**

Source: Cambridge grammar for IELTS.

Could anyone please help me what kind of clause if the bold part? Is it a reduced adjective clause that modify the whole sentence?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you want the meaning or the grammatical function of the clause?

Comment: It describes what happens during, or as an integral part of, the planning phase.  You can understand that clause in relation to "I **plan** my trips very carefully".  Compare: *I **drank** the beer, **tasting** its bitterness*

Comment: It's a gerund-participial clause functioning as a supplementary adjunct. Supplementary adjuncts are not tightly integrated into clause structure, but are set apart in writing by punctuation like a comma, and in speech by a slight pause. Unlike integrated adjuncts, supplementary adjuncts are not modifiers. Semantically, it could be a depictive adjunct, or possibly "implicated reason"; I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 2):

It is an adverbial clause of manner, as it indicates the way in which the subject plans his/her trips.

Comment: Thanks.This clause modifies the verb "plan" , and we have two adverbs for verb plan:"very careful" and "the part after comma' . Am I right? And the last questions: Can I remove comma? and why do we use 'participle' form? And, as I know the clause contain at least one verb and one subject , but we don't have any tense verb in the "adverbial clause of manner". And finally Could you please give more examples to make sense?

Comment: @MickeyMouse, it is true that you have two adverbials of manner there. The second one, which is a clause, can be said to be in apposition to the first one, as it actually describes what "very carefully" consists of. I don't recommend removing the comma. It would get confusing because you have an adverbial of time in between.

Comment: Many Thanks. Is "reading about the places I am going to visit on the Internet and in books" a clause?I get confused, as it doesn't consist  a 'tense verb'.

Comment: Is this correct ? "I am going to continue my education abroad, applying in some well-known universities."

Comment: Adverbial clauses can be reduced or abridged, and this is the case.

Comment: I am going to apply to some well-known universities to continue my education abroad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53449/discussion-between-mickey-mouse-and-gustavson).

Comment: @MickeyMouse I suggest you read about participial clauses and then get back to me, either here or in a chat.